# Avoid changing menu query with suppress_filters => false

Tags: menus, filters, get-posts, posts-where

I recently had to change qTranslate for qTranslate X since the former is not being updated. This broke my menu and after searching I found it was because qTranslate X sets `suppress_filters` to false.

I happen to have `posts_join_paged`, `posts_where` and `posts_orderby` filters in my functions.php and this is breaking my menu.

Is there a condition I could use in those filters to avoid affecting any menus?

I've tried `$query->is_main_query()` inside my filters but I guess menu queries are main queries?

Thanks.

---

### EDIT

Example of one of my filters

```
 function jlb_order_products( $orderby, $query )
 {

     if( !$query->is_main_query() && ( !is_tax( 'collection' ) || is_page_template( 'template-vendeur.php' ) ) )
         return $orderby;

     $orderby = "SUBSTRING( wp_postmeta.meta_value, 22, 14 ) ASC";

     return $orderby;

 }
 add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'jlb_order_products', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Menu queries aren't main queries - there is only ever one and it is... the main query. Update your question with the code for one of your filter functions.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Done.

Comment: have you tried removing the filter within the filter itself? presumably the menu query runs after the main query, so there will be no filter for subsequent queries beyond the first.

Comment: @Milo I just tried this out, and this seems to have fixed the issue, thank you! If you post your comment as an answer I'll select it as the answer after a little bit more testing to be sure.

Comment: You want `!$query->is_main_query() ||`, not `&&`

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Damnit, you're right, thank you. It's always the little mistakes that get me. EDIT: If you post it as an answer I'll mark this as resolved.